# Angular Validators.pattern for password

Tags: angular

Hi i am learning Angular 8 form validators may i know how to use Angular validators to force user to have all these requirement.
- Atleast 1 A-Z
- Atleast 1 a-z
- Atleast 1 0-9
- Atleast 1 special character

This is the code i tried but not working not sure why.

FormGroupCode:

```
newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(50)], Validators.pattern((/?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}/)],
```

HtmlCode:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="newPassword" name="newPassword"
                           placeholder="{{'global.form.newpassword.placeholder' | translate}}"
                           formControlName="newPassword">

                        <small class="form-text text-danger"
                               *ngIf="passwordForm.get('newPassword')?.errors?.pattern">
                            Must have alphanumeric and specia character.
                        </small>
```

Sorry this might be a dumb question but really dono how to solve. 
Appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Validators.pattern(^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$])[a-zA-Z0-9@#%$]{8,16}$)
```

Comment: `newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.pattern('^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@#%$!&*])[a-zA-Z0-9@#%$!&*]{8,50}$')]]`

I modify with add-on some special character and it works perfectly! Appreciate the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the correct signature. A `FormGroup` is an object of many `FormControl`. Here, `FormControl` should have value and validators as its first and second argument.

```
  myFormGroup = {
    newPassword: new FormControl(
      '',
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.pattern(/\d+/)
      ]
    )
  };
```

Form your code, it looks like you used `Validators.pattern` as an `AsyncValidatorFn`, when it is a `ValidatorFn`.